# What is Cost of re initialization of Thread object in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
public class Test extends Activity{

    private MyThread myThread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myThread = new MyThread();
        myThread.start();

        // some code

        if(!myThread.isAlive())
        {
            myThread = new MyThread();
            myThread.start();
        }

        // some code

        if(!myThread.isAlive())
        {
            myThread = new MyThread();
            myThread.start();
        }
    }

    private class MyThread extends Thread
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //some code
            super.run();
        }
    }

}
```

Above code is just an example. As we know once thread obj. done with its task we cannot again start it, for reuse we need to reinitialize thread obj. In example
`myThread` is re initialized for 3 times, so will it cost more for memory if I go on increasing number of re initialization?
If Yes then how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  I don't know Android, but...

How often does your Activity create new threads?  How long do the threads last?  Creating threads *is* somewhat expensive.  No harm if you don't create them very often, but if you are creating many short-lived threads, consider using a *thread pool* instead (e.g., `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`)

Comment: i am developing an android app which involves thermal printing so i have implemented separate thread service for printing. Service is singleton. each time a print request received by the service it first checked if thread is null or not running if yes then new instance of the thread is created.
Now its up to the user on many print request he give. 
What if he give print request for whole day without closing application ?
will GC manage to clear unnecessary thread references ?

Comment: @user1983226, like I said, I don't know android.  Sounds like you want a long-running thread, so my suggestion about using a thread pool probably does not fit your need.  As for garbage collection, a thread's stack will be reclaimed as soon as the thread dies.  After the thread is dead and its stack is gone, the `Thread` object is just like any other object:  It will be reclaimed when there is no variable anywhere in your program that refers to it.